# How to call buildin extension function in same-name extension function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

kotlin has two buildin extension functions in `kotlin.text`:

```
public actual inline fun String.toBoolean()
public actual inline fun String?.toBoolean()
```

Now I want to add `toBoolean` for `Any?`:

```
fun Any?.toBoolean(): Boolean {
    return when(this){
        null -> false
        is Boolean -> this
        is Boolean? -> this

        // Here toBoolean() is this function itself, not kotlin.text.String.toBoolean
        else -> toString().toBoolean()
    }
}
```

in `else -> toString().toBoolean()`, the `toBoolean()` function is not same-name extension function in kotlin.text, see the comment.

I tried to import kotlin.text.toBoolean or kotlin.text.String.toBoolean, but didn't work.

Comment: Maybe `Any.toString().toBoolean()` will work? And couldn't your `Any?.toBoolean` function just call `Any.toBoolean()` ?

Comment: @Andrew it still doesn't work

Comment: You need to import the right package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the function you want to call using a different name like this:

```
import kotlin.text.toBoolean as stringToBoolean

fun Any?.toBoolean(): Boolean {
    return when(this){
        null -> false
        is Boolean -> this
        is Boolean? -> this
        else -> toString().stringToBoolean()
    }
}
```

By the way, `is Boolean? -> this` is a redundant check.

Comment: cannot import kotlin.text.toBoolean, error tip in IDEA

Comment: toBoolean is red, it seems IDEA think kotlin.text.toBoolean doesn't exist

Comment: wow, I invalidate cache and restart IDEA, then it shows me correct and worked...